# Django Forms and bootstrap - adding widgets works but not fully

Tags: django, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, django-forms, django-crispy-forms

I have problem with bootstrap in my django forms. In forms I have this code:

```
make = forms.ChoiceField(choices=make_choices)
make.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-control'})
```

And in tutorials I saw that it should be enough to render proper bootstrap choice field.

But in my case it looks like this:
[image]
Please notice:

- missing arrow indicating actual dropdown on the right
- grey select box is not wide enough, or rather box above is too wide?
- label "Make:" also doesn't look like proper bootstrap label.

I checkout out several tutorials but in all of them adding this "{'class': 'form-control'}" in attrs was enough. I was also experimenting with django crispy forms but they were also not fully correct. What am I missing? What I did wrong?

Comment: setting directly work too:     make = forms.ChoiceField(choices = make_choices,  
                               widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class':'form-select'}),)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

as of bootstrap 5 docs https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.0/forms/select/#default you should use `.form-select` class to trigger the custom styles for `<select>` elements, so it should be

```
make.widget.attrs.update({'class': 'form-select'})
```

`.form-control` class is used for elements like `<input>` and `<textarea>`.

Answer (score 0):

### UPDATE: 2023

```
'field_name': forms.Select( attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
```

If you using **widget** in **Forms.py**

```
class Name(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = modelName
    fields = {'field1', 'field1'}
    widgets = {
        'field1': forms.Select( attrs={'class': 'form-control'})
    }
```